# org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException

Tags: java, hibernate

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ICCID", length=100,unique=true, nullable=false)
private String ICCID;
.....

create table DUMMY_DATA(
    ICCID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
   IMSI  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (ICCID)
);

2015-10-29 13:13:09,883  WARN [SqlExceptionHelper] (SqlExceptionHelper.java:145) - SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000
2015-10-29 13:13:09,883 ERROR [SqlExceptionHelper] (SqlExceptionHelper.java:147) - Field 'ICCID' doesn't have a default value
Oct 29, 2015 1:13:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/globeconnect] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'ICCID' doesn't have a default value
```

I am getting the following exception.
i am reading the content from the file and saving in the data base.
ICCID value will be given from file.
Actually I am setting the file content value to ICCID,can u help me out with where i am going wrong.

Comment: as you have set it not nullable hence you must have to give some default value to it, like empty string

Comment: Which database system are you using? Not all database systems support the @GeneratedValue annotation equally well. Also, on a side note: your annotation says it's length 100 but your create table statement says it's length 255.

Comment: @SSH:@Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name="ICCID", length=100,unique=true, nullable=true)
 private String ICCID;
 @Column(name="IMSI", length=100,unique=true, nullable=true)
 private String IMSI;    still getting same issue.    MYSQL

Comment: @mlkammer: after changing length still having same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must configure the **hbm2ddl.auto** in the hibernate configuration file :

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

after run 1 time the app .

and change it to update , like this :

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

The problem is you have some old values inserted in the table and when you want to change the schema , there is no default value for those old values .